# count total transaction with in a date range

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this data:
tb_Leave

```
id   |   empID   |  startDate   |   endDate
1    |     1     |  01/02/2014  |  01/05/2014     ------ 2, 3, 4, 5
2    |     2     |  01/03/2014  |  01/03/2014     ------ 3
3    |     3     |  01/04/2014  |  01/07/2014     ------ 4, 5, 6, 7
4    |     4     |  01/03/2014  |  01/07/2014     ------ 3, 4, 5, 6, 7
5    |     5     |  01/09/2014  |  01/09/2014     ------ 9
```

I want to return all the total leave with in a specific days.
out put:

```
total   |   Date
  1     |   01/02/2014
  3     |   01/03/2014
  3     |   01/04/2014
  3     |   01/05/2014
  2     |   01/06/2014
  2     |   01/07/2014
  1     |   01/09/2014
```

Comment: Does it have to be a single query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can expand the dates using a recursive CTE and then use `group by`:

```
with cte as (
      select startdate as thedate, enddate
      from tb_leave
      union all
      select dateadd(day, 1, startdate), enddate
      from cte
      where startdate < enddate
)
select thedate, count(*)
from cte
group by thedate
with (MAXRECURSION 0);
```

Note:  this assumes that there are not more than 99 days for one row.  Otherwise, add a `MAXRECURSION` option.  You can also do this by joining in a numbers table, such as `spt_values`:

```
select dateadd(day, v.number - 1, startdate) as thedate, count(*)
from tb_leave l join
     spt_values v
     on dateadd(day, v.number - 1, startdate) <= l.enddate
group by dateadd(day, v.number - 1, startdate)
order by 1;
```

Comment: on the 1st query i'm having this
The statement terminated. The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion.